# Instrumenting Linux kernel functions

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, instrumentation

I am looking for a way to instrument a function in Linux kernel. It seems that GCC's -finstrument-functions flag allows instrumentation, but is there any way to instrument only a particular Linux function using compiler directives (i.e., function attributes) instead of instrumenting all functions?

It seems that KProbe also has functionality of instrumentation, but KProbe maintains a blacklist of functions and does not allow to monitor those functions, resulting limited scope of instrumentation.

I am running Ubuntu-16.04 with kernel version 4.8.11 on x86_64.

The purpose of instrumentation is to monitor the entry and exit of the target function by setting and clearing a flag.

Comment: `but is there any way to instrument subset of Linux functions using compiler directives?` - Yes. Describe (in the question post) what do you want to achieve eventually.

Comment: I think the idea of instrumentation is performing some operation in __cyg_profile_func_enter and __cyg_profile_func_exit.. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Requirement `instrument subset of Linux functions` is too vague. There is `-finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list` option for gcc to exclude some functions from instrumentation. Does it fit for your purpose?

Comment: Actually, I don't need alternative solution that you propose. I am looking for exactly what I mentioned in my question. How can I put compiler directives in function definition so that gcc can only instrument those functions? Is it even possible?

Comment: @ProbirRoy, so, you would like to tell the compiler to instrument some particular functions but leave the rest alone. The question is still unclear: what do you mean by "compiler directives"? Compiler flags like -f<something>? Function attributes? #pragmas? Can you change the code you would like to instrument? Or you can only change build options?

Comment: Please be more specific about the original problem you are trying to solve with such instrumentation. If you only need to execute your code at the beginning or/and at the end of some kernel functions, take a look at [kprobes and kretprobes](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/kprobes.txt), as well as at [kprobe-based trace events](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/trace/kprobetrace.rst) They might do the thing for you, depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Eugene, Thanks for explaining it to me. I can see my question is incomplete.  Probably, function attributes are the right thing I am looking for. I want to mark the entry and exit of the Kprobe's blacklisted functions in a flag during runtime (setting and clearing flag bits). As Kprobe itself mark them blacklisted and does not monitor, I think I will not be able to use Kprobe.

Comment: @Eugene, I can modify the code as well as build options to make appropriate changes if necessary.

Comment: "Kprobe itself mark them blacklisted" - could you edit your question and specify these functions? Please also specify Linux distro and kernel version, as well as arch (x86_64, arm, ppc, whatever) - if you want to instrument such functions, the answers may depend on that. If I understand you correctly, you want to add your code at the entry and the exit of these functions and you want to be able to turn on/off execution of that code in runtime, not during compilation. Is that correct?

Comment: @Eugene, I don't want to turn on/off the execution of the function, I want to set a flag when the function is being executed. Eventually, I want to monitor resource usage pattern during the execution of these functions at runtime. I have updated my question.

Comment: Well, I was not talking about turning on/off the execution of the function in runtme. It was about *your* code added to these functions. By the way, as you can modify the kernel source code and rebuild the kernel, why not do it straightforward: add a global variable and some code to the sources of the needed functions to set/clear that variable? Especially if you do not need to enable/disable such monitoring in runtime. If that was needed, a writable kernel parameter or a file in debugfs that turns your monitoring on or off, would also do. Or?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is it depends. However it is not as straightforward to inject as one might think.

In particular, example you can use -finstrument-functions for specific C files and then use attribute((no_instrument_function)) to exclude the ones you *don't want instrumented*

You would have to keep track of preemption and fastcalls, you would have to make sure that you're not accidentally stopping or removing instrumentation. Oh you also have to track any random stack layout that the kernel is self inflicting.